# clearPackagePreferredActivities exception with Android multi accounts

Tags: android, user-accounts

I'm trying to unset my app default actions with :

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();              
pm.clearPackagePreferredActivities( getPackageName() );
```

It works with the primary account of the device but it throws an exception with secondary accounts:

> "Neither user 1010080 nor current process has android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS."

Of course I added `android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS` to the manifest (but I think it is not used anymore)

I tried "to change the context" with something like:

```
 final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
 pm.clearPackagePreferredActivities( getPackageName() );
```

without success.

My App is an Home Application (for kids) that locks almost everything  and I want a 'quit' button that restore user home (or the choice of home at least). May be there's another solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm... that's odd. I would expect a user to be able to clear his or her own defaults. To me, it feels like a bug. You might want to create a reproducible test case and file an issue on http://b.android.com, if nobody else comes up with something more concrete for you.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, an user should be able to clear his or her own defaults. May be I'm not in the right context for the  `PackageManager` or the `PackageName` don't refer to the package of the secondary account or something like that...

Answer (score 1):

[clearPackagePreferredActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#clearPackagePreferredActivities%28java.lang.String%29)  &  [addPackageToPreferred](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#addPackageToPreferred%28java.lang.String%29) are deprecated by android since API level 8.

A modern method to set preferred activity is to start an intent, like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Yes `addPackageToPreferred` is deprecated since API Level 8 but `clearPackagePreferredActivities` seems not. 
My Problem is not to set but to clear/unset my activity as the prefered activity. (`clearPackagePreferredActivities` do the job  with the main android account, the problem is when the app is used from a secondary account)

Comment: The code you gave working well, but once i choose ( Always ) from its dialog , it do not prompt next time. i want to prompt it every time when user need to change the home app.